# Ender Chest open and Close animation

Tags: java, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

I want an ender chest open event to be cancelled and to show the open and close animation when right clicked. my current code is:

```
public void changeChestState(Location loc, boolean open) {
    if (open) {
        for (Player p : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
            p.playNote(loc, (byte) 1, (byte) 1);
        }
    } else {
         for (Player p : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
             p.playNote(loc, (byte) 1, (byte) 0);
         }
    }
}
```

When I right click the chest I hear the sound, but no animation happens. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can send a `PacketPlayOutBlockAction` packet to the player to make them see the chest open or close. This packet is used to display note particles, piston movements and chest state changes as well.

You'll need to create a `BlockPosition` and get the NMS `Block` (the type of minecraft block, in this case a chest) as well as provide two bytes of data. The first byte is not used in the case of the chest animation, and the second byte represents the change in state of the chest, 0 for a closing and 1 for an opening chest. Below is your method rewritten to also show the corresponding animation.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static void changeChestState(Location loc, boolean open) {
    byte dataByte = (open) ? (byte) 1 : 0; // The byte of data used for the note and animation packet (1 if true, 0 if false)
    for (Player player : Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
        player.playNote(loc, (byte) 1, dataByte); // Play the sound
        BlockPosition position = new BlockPosition(loc.getBlockX(), loc.getBlockY(), loc.getBlockZ()); // Create the block position using loc
        // Instantiate animation packet, get NMS Block using getById() and loc.getBlock() (deprecated), the server version may vary
        PacketPlayOutBlockAction blockActionPacket = new PacketPlayOutBlockAction(position, net.minecraft.server.v1_8_R3.Block.getById(loc.getBlock().getTypeId()), (byte) 1, dataByte);
        ((CraftPlayer) player).getHandle().playerConnection.sendPacket(blockActionPacket); // Send animation packet to CraftPlayer
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you to much! This has helped tremendously. It's perfect!